# Apache Solr 7.4 : Nesting with "_childDocuments_" not working, the document is still flat

Tags: apache, solr

My use case is this : I have a Parent -> Children -> GrandChildren hierarchy.

I would like to ingest documents as nested and would like to do BlockJoin queries to retrieve all grandchildren of a particular parent, all children of particular parent etc.

I have defined the appropriate fields in the schema (using curl) and copy fields and field-types as required by my application. I have also defined "text" as a copy field for everything as I have to support random searches.

I have defined the document to ingest as follows :

```
{

"id": "3443",

"path": "1.employee",

"employeeId": 3443,

"employeeName": "Tom",

"employeeCounty": "Maricopa",

"_childDocuments_": [{

    "id": "3443.54545454",

    "path": "2.employee.assets",

    "assetId": 54545454,

    "assetName": "Lenovo",

    "assetType": "Laptop",

    "_childDocuments_": [{

        "id": "3443.54545454.5764646",

        "path": "3.employee.assets.assetType",

        "processorId": 5764646,

        "processorType": "Intel core i7"
    }]
}]
```

}

Now when I query using the Admin UI, I am getting the following flattened out object, also block join queries don't work as well :

```html
        {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1533252181415"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"3443",
        "employeeId":3443,
        "text":["3443",
          "Tom",
          "Maricopa"],
        "employeeName":"Tom",
        "employeeCounty":"Maricopa",
        "_childDocuments_.id":[3443.54545454,
          3443.643534544],
        "_childDocuments_.path":["2.employee.assets],
        "_childDocuments_.assetId":[54545454,
          643534544],
        "_childDocuments_.assetName":["Lenovo"],
```

What am I missing? How can I make Solr process the nested documents like they are supposed to be rather than flattening them out?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution. I was using the wrong URL to post.
I was using `http://localhost:8983/solr/my-core/update/json/docs`

Instead I should just use `http://localhost:8983/solr/my-core/update`
Because I am already formatting the doc in Solr format and Solr neednt do any special processing to index it.